# Change key icon on a softkeyboard in run time

Tags: android, keyboard, icons

I'm trying to change a key icon on press on a softkeyboard in run time with:

```
@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();
    List<Keyboard.Key> keys = currentKeyboard.getKeys();
    mInputView.invalidateKey(primaryCode);

    keys.get(primaryCode).label = null;
    keys.get(primaryCode).icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);

}
```

It works, but when I press a key, change the icon of other key. Do U know why?

(I'm using API level 8)

Comment: What do you mean by **It works, but when I press a key, change the icon of other key.**

Comment: For example, if I tap on "a" key, the "f" key icon changes and the "a" key doesn't change. But I want to change the "a" key icon...

Comment: I never did this myself, so I had to write a custom keyboard code to see whats happening here and finally I found what is wrong in your code. Please see my answer.

Comment: Do let me know if my solution works for you. Its a working code at my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) 
{
    Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();            
    List<Keyboard.Key> keys = currentKeyboard.getKeys();
    mInputView.invalidateKey(primaryCode);

    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++ )
    {
        Keyboard.Key currentKey = keys.get(i);

        //If your Key contains more than one code, then you will have to check if the codes array contains the primary code
        if(currentKey.codes[0] == primaryCode) 
        {
            currentKey.label = null;
            currentKey.icon = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
            break; // leave the loop once you find your match
        }
    }
}
```

**Reason your code is not working:** The culprit here is `keys.get(primaryCode)`. You need to get the `Key` from Keys list. Because `get()` method of a `List` expects the position of the object you want to fetch. But you are not passing they position of the object, rather than you are passing the unicode value of the key. So, all I did was to fetch the `Key` correctly from the `List` using its position. Now, I got the position by running a `for` loop and comparing each `Key`'s unicode value with currently pressed `Key`'s unicode value.

**Note:** In some cases one `Key` has more than one unicode value. In that case you will have to change the `if` statement in which you will check if codes array contains the `primaryCode`.

Comment: That's perfect, works perfectly. Thanks. I just remove the "-1" from `for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++ )` to include the last key. And the `getDrawable` says that's deprecated.

Comment: There must be some new advanced method in place of `getDrawable`. I put it just for testing.